# How would you say "a few" in French?

Tags: choix-de-mot

In English, the phrase "a few" has a specific meaning. It means three instances of something. If I wanted to say, "I only have a few (of something)" in French, what would be the best word choice?

I can think of a couple possibilities myself.

> Example: I only have a few hours.
>
> Je n'ai que plusieurs heures.
>
> Je n'ai que quelques heures.

What would be best? If you can think of a better word, please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only have a few hours = Je n'ai que quelques heures

I have several hours = J'ai plusieurs heures

I only have 3 hours = Je n'ai que trois heures

Comment: What about "je n'ai que peu d'heures"?

Comment: "Peu" fonctionne mal avec "heures". Plutôt : "Je n'ai que peu de temps"

Comment: Je partage que ça sonne mal, pourtant B.2 ("peu de jours") ici  http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/peu

Comment: "Un absence de peu de jours", ça va, parce que c'est "de peu", mais "que peu d'heures" ça n'est pas standard.

Comment: _Peu de jours_ is ok, _peu d'heures_ by itself is not. However you could say _il ne me reste que peu d'heures à vivre_.

Comment: Oh, bien trouvé, je me demande si c'est le complément d'objet indirect qui rend cette formulation acceptable

Comment: *Je n'ai que peu d'heures à vous consacrer* me semble tout à fait audible... Je ne vois pas le problème...

Comment: *Je n'ai que peu d'heures pour faire du sport*, *je n'ai que peu d'heures avant le départ de mon train*... Par rapport à *quelques*, j'insiste sur le fait que c'est pas beaucoup et que c'est compliqué. Je ne vois pas le problème.

Comment: Ça fonctionne parce qu'il y a un complément à la suite de "que peu d'heures". Le problème c'est lorsqu'il n'y en a pas : "Je n'ai que peu d'heures".   Mais comme vous dîtes : bof